# save records even if we have errors in some of them

Tags: entity-framework

I copy much data from another database to my database which has got different structure than mine - I create objects, add them to `DbSet` and call `SaveChanges()` method. But if one record is invalid then method `SaveChanges()` throws error and no records are inserted in database. I would like to save correct records instead - how can I do that in `Entity Framework`?

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

Gifts gift1 = new Gifts();
gift1.Name = "test1";
gift1.Price = 5;
db.Gifts.Add(gift1);

// Here ERROR - because name can't be NULL:
Gifts gift2 = new Gifts();
gift2.Name = null;
gift2.Price = 5;
db.Gifts.Add(gift2);

Gifts gift3 = new Gifts();
gift3.Name = "test3";
gift3.Price = 5;
db.Gifts.Add(gift3);

// .....

DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose code in `try catch` blocks and save each entity saperately:

```
DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

try{
    Gifts gift1 = new Gifts();
    gift1.Name = "test1";
    gift1.Price = 5;
    db.Gifts.Add(gift1);

    DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch{}

// Here ERROR - because name can't be NULL:
try{
    Gifts gift2 = new Gifts();
    gift2.Name = null;
    gift2.Price = 5;
    db.Gifts.Add(gift2);

    DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch{}

try{   
    Gifts gift3 = new Gifts();
    gift3.Name = "test3";
    gift3.Price = 5;
    db.Gifts.Add(gift3);

    DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch{}
```

Comment: But I think it can be too slow if I call SaveChanges() for each entity because I have 1 million entities, am I right?

Comment: Of course this will never end for million entities. Then why not to apply validations in app layer?